# Postdoctoral funding for scientists with career breaks

Tags: postdocs, career-path, job-search, job, europe

I've finished my PhD in pure math in October 2013, did four years of postdocs in applied math/machine learning applied to computational neuroimaging. Following that, I've worked in industry in 2018-2020 (where I got fired several times and went through periods of unemployment, including one from June 2020 to August 2021) and then from September 2021, I'm in a teaching only position, but as a freelancer, not with an employee contract.

I'm based in Western Europe, and I'm looking for postdoctoral fundings the EU) in Europe (including the UK and Ireland as well as  geared towards people with a career break like myself, ideally in applied math/computational neuroimaging/computer vision/geometric statistics or machine learning.

I looked for this online, and so far, have found [this](https://www.ukri.org/what-we-offer/developing-people-and-skills/mrc/funding-for-biomedical-research-and-innovation/career-re-entry-awards/) and [this](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/parents-network/grants-for-academic-returners/), but the problem is to find postdoc funding that are a bit more specialaized towards an applied mathematician like myself. Are there possibly any such designated funding/fellowships the links don't cover or should I know about in general?

Comment: Two points - firstly, you may be hoping for too close a match, fellowships with a very narrow discipline focus and a career re-entry focus are going to be rare or non-existent. Secondly, from your description above I wouldn't describe you as having had a career break - you've been working in different areas, but 'career break' usually implies not working at all professionally for personal reasons. There may be some fellowships which use a broader definition, but from your description above you wouldn't be eligible for most career re-entry fellowships that I'm aware of.

Comment: @StephenMcMahon Thank you for the pointers - appreciate them! In fact I did have several unemployments between January 2018 and August 2021, one of them lasting from June 2020-August 2021, so these can be proven. Next, in my current teaching only position, I'm working as a freelancer (so not with an employee contract), so I think this can viewed as a break, no? Thirdly, I was fired several times when I worked in industry. So given all these facts, will I still not be eligible for a career re-entry fellowship, and if not, then what fellowship can I apply to?

Comment: The problem is not that your unemployement was documented. The thing is that you were working all the time (consider being unemployed as a job, the job of finding a job, a job that in civil countries is funded by public money for obvious reasons).

If you had other breaks, for example because of providing support to some family member or to take care of your own health, then it is a different matter and re-entry fellowship are thoughts for these cases, in general.

Comment: Being unemployed (or underemployed) is not the same as a career break. It sounds like you were able to work and actively seeking employment for this period, so I wouldn't consider those career breaks. On the 'what fellowship' question - Do you think there should be fellowship schemes tailored to your position? You can apply for general fellowship calls, but these are highly competitive and, to be frank, you may struggle with your CV as described (out of research for a long time, fired from multiple roles). I wouldn't say it's impossible, but you should carefully consider your goals here.

Comment: Unemployment may count as a career break. It depends on the funder.

E.g. the UK social sciences funding body says that "Career breaks include periods of maternity, sick leave, or unemployment" (https://social.sgsss.ac.uk/files/documents/fellowships/02.-esrc-pdf-faqs-2021-22.pdf).

But the Royal Society talks about "time away due to personal reasons such as... caring responsibilities; ill-health or working in a non-research environment/role, such as industry". (https://royalsociety.org/-/media/grants-schemes-awards/grants/dorothy-hodgkin/Dorothy_Hodgkin_Fellowship_Scheme_Notes_2024.pdf)